# List for all disable triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to make a list of all triggers which aren't running.

```
declare @Trigger nvarchar(150) 
select @Trigger = t1.name from  sys.triggers as t1 WHERE t1.is_disabled = 1
declare @disable int 
select @disable =t1.is_disabled FROM sys.triggers t1 WHERE t1.is_disabled = 0
While @disable <= 1
BEGIN
    Print 'Trigger ' + @Trigger +  ' is disable!'
    set @disable = @disable + 1
END
```

As a result I have only one trigger, but there are another 10 which are disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` here at all? Why not just `SELECT` the ones that are disabled?

Comment: I need to print which of all is not running

Comment: "I need to print" *Why*? `PRINT` isn't for returning data to the presentation layer; that's what `SELECT` is for (and `OUTPUT` parameters). Smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Your concept of variables needs some refreshing I think, `@trigger` is a variable and can store a single value - if you have 1 disabled trigger or 100, it is only ever going to store the last one from the result-set returned, which is arbitrary. Just remove the variable assignment and list them?!

Comment: Your looping logic does not work - something that anyone with years of experience should see. Your first assignment to `@disable` does what? Assigns the value of zero. Does zero indicate a trigger is disabled? No, it does not. Notice that the query that assigns `@trigger` uses different logic.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT 
    t2.[name] TableTriggerReference
    , SCHEMA_NAME(t2.[schema_id]) TableSchemaName
    , t3.[rowcnt] TableReferenceRowCount
    , t1.[name] TriggerName
    , 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t2.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t2.[name]) + ' ENABLE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(t1.[name]) ScriptToEnableThem
FROM sys.triggers t1
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t2 ON t2.object_id = t1.parent_id
    INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes t3 On t2.object_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.is_disabled = 1
    AND t1.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND t1.parent_class = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from sys.triggers trg  
where is_disabled = 1
```

Comment: The OP appears to already know this is the right query though, as they have this query in their question; just with (flawed) variable assignment.